# setText() not working in fabricjs version 2

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

I am trying to set text to textbox explicitly. In an older fabricjs version

```
object.setText("something")
```

was working, but no longer in fabricjs version 2. Is there any other way introduced in this version?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text1 = new fabric.Textbox('Text', {
    left: 10,
    top: 20,
    width: 300
})

canvas.add(text1);
canvas.on('text:changed', function(e) {
    var objTEmp = e.target;
    objTEmp.setText("some");
});
```

```css
canvas{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.0-rc.4/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That build doesn't have setter/getter (optional). If you want to set text you can use

```js
obj.text = text;
//or
obj.set({
    text:text
});
//or
obj.set('text', text);
```

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text1 = new fabric.Textbox('Text', {
  left: 10,
  top: 20,
   width: 300
})

canvas.add(text1);
canvas.on('text:changed', function(e) {
 var objTEmp = e.target;
 objTEmp.set({
  text : "some"
 });
});
```

```css
canvas{
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.0-rc.4/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own version of Fabric.js here: http://fabricjs.com/build/

Check "Named accessors" to bring back support for setters and getters. Not recommended and unsupported, who knows how long it will stay in there, but if you just need a quick solution now, that will do the trick.